# Display dependent and controlling picklists in lwc

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am a rookie in lwc and javascript. I have a requirement to display all the dependent picklists and controlling picklists in the object . Can you someone guide me on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Check this example (https://technogeeksfdc.wordpress.com/2020/07/04/dependent-picklist-in-lwc/)

Comment: Thank you . But here we are using the combobox. I don't want a drop down to select. I need to display all the values at once without any event. That is what I am struggling to understand.